# How to deal with a git that has git-svn and pure git remotes

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have two repositories, one is still an *svn* and acts as the main place, and another is pure *git* where is the daily work. I've my local clone using `git svn clone svn+ssh://...` and adding a remote using `git remote add git@...`.

After a refactoring with its commits and branches, the *git* master has the directory structure modified and when I try to `git svn dcommit` a bunch of conflicts arise in what looks like a rebase to the *svn*. It's like the *mv* of files and directories to rename and relocate are lost.

The solutions I'm reading looks that comes from scenarios where both remote are being committed at the same time, and even this can cause issues. Is there a way to tell *git-svn* to act like *strategy is to convert the svn to what git has*?

**Update @ 20140821**

After a while I've found how it can work for me, but I'm not sure this would be enough generic.

In my case I'm having both remotes with the same commits, that is when I do a `push` just before or after I'll do a `dcommit`. Then I can force myself to always start by the git and then continue with svn.

It looks like:

```
git svn fetch
git fetch gitremote
git add file1 file2
git commit -m "something descriptive but concise"
git push gitremote branch
git svn dcommit
```

The only way I've found sending the commit first to svn, is to use the option *--force* in the push, because otherwise the `status`command was including a message:

```
# Your branch and 'gitremote/branch' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
```

And any try to merge shows all the changes made in the `commit` like new. But this *force* looks to have a big issue if there are other changes in the git repository (for example another developer has already pushed something there), then this force may overwrite those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid history rewrite (git push) on the git remote side you could simply do a merge. In the simplest case, where you have pushed your changes to `svn/branch` and have a corresponding `git_remote/branch` with no difference:

```
git checkout git_remote/branch
# -s ours to ignore potential conflicts, assuming git diff is empty
git merge -s ours svn/branch
git push git_remote HEAD:branch
```