# Git/svn - keeping synced two repositories with different access rights

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

There is just too much information online for me to understand and be able to get my own picture, so I gently ask the community to provide light to my journey...

My situation:

- we have a SVN server behind a firewall within our company. Impossible to move to DMZ.
- we need some third party (our client) to access part of the source code from a remote location, since they are contributing to the development. BUT they are not from our company, so I cannot provide them VPN access. I need them to be able not only to read source, but also commit changes.
- our SVN repo contains ALL our product. I want to give access to ONLY some folders to my client.
- My company is VERY reluctant to let us buy a private GitHub account... for security reason, not cost...

We are trying for a few months the following, but it just doesn't work since it requires manual sync:

- rent a virtual machine online. Install a Git server. provide access to both our developers and our client.
- make an initial checkout of the reduced number of svn folders I want to share.
- We all work: either improving the code in these folders or creating new source code and folders.
- our developers are supposed to update/commits the two repos by hand... And this just does occur...

So I'm looking for solutions to automatically sync, but keeping in mind the access rights...
I've seen this... Would it work for me? http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Another worry is that our company will during next year migrate all our SVN to Git...
I have no issue in anticipating this and running our own git server instead of the SVN, but it will have to be kept behind the firewall. Then I'm lost with the "clone", "mirror" aspects and to maintain the correct access rights...

What solution/advice could you provide us in terms of this distributed architecture?

Comment: This might get a better response on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: @PatrickQuirk: Actually, I think it's more on-topic here. Yes, it is a question concerning "professional system and network administrators", but it is also a question about a SW development tool, which *is* on-topic here. Since it's really more about the specifics of version control, I feel it's more appropriate here.

Comment: One thing that I am not clear is: suposing that I host all my code in a new git server, could I allow my client (specific user) to Fork only some sub-folders? and then send pull requests for merging/integration?

Comment: @DamienSalle I wasn't arguing whether it was on topic, just that it might get a better response.  Mainly because the last sentence implies you need help setting up a distributed system, which the community at Server Fault would probably more quickly answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, git-svn won't work automatically and smoothly in a generic case. Main problem would be that git-svn'ed commits will get different SHAs and that would make keeping both sides synced a challenging manual task if the rate of changes from both git and svn sides is high.

If you can limit the changes to go only from git to svn, it might be feasible to maintain the sync by technique similar to [How to deal with a git that has git-svn and pure git remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137439/how-to-deal-with-a-git-that-has-git-svn-and-pure-git-remotes/27004533#27004533)

Answer (score 0):

As Mykola Gurov's answer explains, `git svn` will probably not work in this case.

However, you should be able to solve this without git:

- Give the developer access to just your SVN server, using a (properly secured) reverse HTTP proxy. The proxy will have to be exposed to the internet (or to a dedicated VPN for the remote dev), thus should require a login and run over HTTPS.
- Set up an SVN user account for the remote dev.
- On the SVN server, set up [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) such that the remote dev can only read and commit where they're supposed to.

This will require some manual setup work, but it should work, and be secure.